# How can I get a CSRF token from the command line?

Tags: django, django-csrf

I'm frequently testing my application using `curl` and in the past I've had to simply wrap my views with `csrf_exempt`. I really don't want to do this, as I have a nasty feeling that I'll forget to do this in deployment and enjoy a lifetime of CSRF hell.

Is there a way for me to request a CSRF token using Django's shell commands? I'd like to get a token I could send with my `curl` requests to test things safely.

Comment: Just issue a GET request and parse the HTML.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Make an initial GET request to the form URL in order to fill the cookie jar:

```
$ curl http://example.com/some-form/ -o /dev/null -c cookies.txt -s
```

Get the value of the `csrftoken` cookie:

```
$ grep csrftoken cookies.txt | cut -f 7
YQkfXZCKtPP0hC30NmH10jSWuf6yJA5E
```

When issuing a POST, just include a `csrfmiddlewaretoken` field with this value (and use the same cookie jar).

I use the same trick to write end-to-end tests using the `requests` library.

Answer (score 2):

you can do like this

```
from django.middleware.csrf import _get_new_csrf_key()
request.META["CSRF_COOKIE"] = _get_new_csrf_key()
```

Comment: Typo: `from django.middleware.csrf import _get_new_csrf_key` (without brackets)

Answer (score 0):

While working on an issue related to this, I wanted to test setting CSRF tokens for a bunch of endpoints that are accessible via AJAX. I came upon this thread and thought it might be worth it to add one other way to do it from the Django shell, which is what the original poster seemed to be asking about.

First of all, I am using the `requests` library, so if you don't have it you have to do `pip install requests`.

**Ensure Token Exists**

Next, if dealing only with Ajax endpoints, we need some way of retrieving a token, so the get method of your view must have the following decorator set, because [as mentioned in the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/csrf/) the token won't be set if you're generating forms dynamically. Here's a class-based-views example:

```
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.views.decorators.csrf import ensure_csrf_cookie

    @method_decorator(ensure_csrf_cookie)
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return SomeJson...
```

**DRF Post: Ensure csrf_protect**

I am also using Django Rest Framework views, so I had to explicitly set `csrf_protect` on my POST:

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect

    @method_decorator(ensure_csrf_cookie)
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return SomeJson...
```

**Retrieve token from shell and POST it back**

Finally, to get a token from the `get` method and POST it back to the `post` method, I did the following:

```
>>> resp = requests.get(url)
>>> cookies = resp.cookies
>>> token = cookies['csrftoken']
>>> data = {'content': True, 'we': None, 'are': False, 'posting': 0}
>>> data['csrfmiddlewaretoken'] = token
>>> resp2 = requests.post(url, data=data, cookies=cookies)
>>> resp2
<Response [200]>
```